# Best local sockets naming practice

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I have found the [example](http://netcins.ceid.upatras.gr/OpSys-I/project/server_client.htm) of using the `local sockets`. The code from examle uses the path

```
#define UNIXSTR_PATH "/tmp/unix.str"
```

as the name of a socket. Is this a best practice of choosing the socket name? Should I use something like

```
/var/run/com.company.executable.socket
```

writing the daemon on Linux Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it in `/var/run` is fine, but the sockets are usually named after the executable itself and not in some Javaesque fashion.